# Is there a module or simple way to allow the cc.net.config file to be seen from the webdashboard?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'd like to be able to have either web dashboard logged in administrators or general users depending on which the team prefers be able to see the contents of this file without remoting into the box, is this possible using the webdashboard?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to how it can be seen from the web dashboard...

... but it is possible to store the ccnet.config file in source control and set up a special build on the build server that automatically retrieves the newest config file.

This way you do not even have to remote into the box in order to *edit* the contents of the file.

See more details in the documentation:
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configure+CruiseControl.Net+to+Automatically+Update+its+Config+File